# mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user (using password: YES) when trying to connect server

Tags: mysql

I use the following query when I want to copy a MySQL database:

```
mysqldump --opt -h HOSTNAME -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD DATABASENAME| gzip > name.sql
```

But I get this error:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user  (using password: YES) when trying to connect server
```

When I was looking for a solution I found a lot of answers, but in every case the problem appears on localhost - I have this problem in my hosting...could anyone help?

Comment: Sorry for my English, as you can see I'm not expert :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to remove the space between `-p` and `PASSWORD`

```
mysqldump --opt -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -proot DATABASENAME| gzip > name.sql
```

User: root
Password: root

The password parameter must be concatenated to the parameter.
Anyway, check your credentials too!

PS: `name.sql` should be `name.sql.zip`

Answer (score 0):

There could be some special char like:

```
$ & ! \ [ ] < > \ `
```

on your password. test with a simple password if it works then increase the password complexity

The other way to test is add `-p` on your command which will prompt the password. if you provide on prompt it will work for sure if the password is correct.

```
mysqldump -uroot  -h localhost  dbname -p | gzip -c > /backup/ac.gz
```